# Excel Macro Structured Column References

Tags: excel

So I've been using the below code example to great success. It takes a previously copied selection and then switches to another page, starting at the first line of code below. It searched for the last row with data, then returns that row value then adds+1, then pastes the selection at that location.

I want to change the code to use structured references, instead of column(4) I want to use the name of the column: "CCMS Notification". Also the table name is "OpenComplaints".

If there was a way to skip using LastRow2 entirely and paste directly to the end of the table that'd be great. Thank you for any help anyone can give me.

```
Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").Select
With activesheets
Dim LastRow2 As Long
    LastRow2 = Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").ListObjects("OpenComplaints").Range.Columns(4).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
End With

Range("D" & LastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to replace all your code by :

```
Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").Range("OpenComplaints[CCMS Notification]").Offset(Range("OpenComplaints[CCMS Notification]").Count, 0).Resize(1).pastespecial xlpastevalues
```

Note that it'll paste after the last row of the "OpenComplaints" table whether or not the column has data.

To paste after the last "blank" cell :

```
Sheets("BP -Tracker - Open Complaints").Range("OpenComplaints[CCMS Notification]").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you, your second selection is exactly what I was looking for. It just needs the "Paste:" before the "xlPasteValues".

Thank you so much!